# Looping through array with IF comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to Javascript and encounter some problem. I am trying to compare the Array words to the Array days. If the ***word*** from **Array words** is not equal to ***day*** in **Array days**, the **word** will be pushed to **name Array**. I tried to use the script below, but it gives me different answer.

I am looking to get only the Name (Joe Smith) from the words array and will exclude the day if ever there is one.

```
function newFunction () {
 var days = new Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
 var words = new Array("Joe", "Smith", "Tuesday");
 var name = new Array();
 var day = "";
 for (x in words) {
  for (y in days) {
    if (words[x] == days[x]) {
      day = days[x];
   } else {
      name.push(words[x]);
  };
 };
  return name;
}
```

When I run the script, I got this result.

**Result
Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,Smith,Smith,Smith,Smith,Smith,Smith,Smith,Tuesday,Tuesday,Tuesday**

Comment: use `words.filter(v => !days.includes(v))`, instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are looking in the `days` array, but still adding it to `names` even though it is somewhere else in the array.

Here is a solution in simple JS:

```
function NewFunction (){
    let days = new Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
    let words = new Array("Joe", "Smith", "Tuesday");
    let name = new Array();
    let day = "";
    for(let i in words){
        let found = false;
        for(let j in days){
            if(words[i] == days[j]){
                day = days[j];
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            name.push(words[i]);
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Notice that I am looking for the word, but not adding it in the second loop, only setting a variable that it has been found and adding it outside

Note: There are much cleaner ways to do this with a little bit more advanced JS

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=it) as suggested in the comment or fix the mistake you have in the inner loop. Change it from:

```
for (y in days) {
   if (words[x] == days[x]) {
      day = days[x];
   } else {
     name.push(words[x]);
   }
}
```

to:

```
for (y in days) {
    if (words[x] == days[y]) {
        name.push(words[x]);
    }
}
```

The snippet:

```js
function newFunction() {
    var days = new Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
    var words = new Array("Joe", "Smith", "Tuesday");
    var name = new Array();
    var day = "";
    for (x in words) {
        for (y in days) {
            if (words[x] == days[y]) {
                name.push(words[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return name;
}
console.log(newFunction());
```